# Convert the http response body to JSON format using Unirest C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, unirest, mashape

I am using mashape api: https://market.mashape.com/montanaflynn/dictionary

Here's my code:

```
HttpResponse<RootObject> response = Unirest.get("https://montanaflynn-dictionary.p.mashape.com/define?word=irony")
    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "my mashape key")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .asJson<RootObject>();
```

I generated the RootObject class using: http://json2csharp.com/

Here's my RootObject class code:

```
class Definition
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string attribution { get; set; }
}

class RootObject
{
    public List<Definition> definitions { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in unirest-net.dll
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to type 'RootObject'.**

**Question:** How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It must be placed in an asynchronous function:

```
static async Task<RootObject> GetRootInfo()
{
     HttpResponse<RootObject> response = await Unirest.get("https://montanaflynn-dictionary.p.mashape.com/define?word=irony")
    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "my mashape key")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .asJsonAsync<RootObject>();

     return response.Body;
}
```